# Let $I$ be a two-sided ideal of a ring $R$. Show: An abelian group $M$ is a left $(R/I)$-module iff $M$ is a left $R$-module annihilated by $I$.

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, modules, ideals

I have so far figured out neither of the directions of the proof. I have a very specific point I am stuck at right now. I am trying to prove the "$\Leftarrow$"-direction at the moment, so I presume $M$ to be a left $R$-module that is annihilated by $I$. For $M$ to be a module, there has to be some sort of scalar multiplication operation $\cdot :R\times M\to M$. How can I construct another scalar multiplication operation $\cdot:(R/I)\times M\to M$ from this, so that I can show the requested regularity properties for $M$ to be a module of $(R/I)$?

Comment: "requested regularity properties"? Does this mean "the axioms (of a module)"?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Define the left-action of $R/I$ on $M$: $(a+I)m = am$ for all $m\in M$ and $a\in R$.

Let $i\in I$. Then $(a+i+I) m = (a+i)m$.
If $M$ is annihilated by $I$, then $im= 0$ and so $(a+i)m = am$, i.e., $(a+i+I)m = (a+I)m$. This shows the well-definedness of the above left-action.

Comment: Thank you very much! This seems like a promising path :)